# Expanding/Duplicating dataframe rows based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am an R user who has recently started using Python 3 for data management. I am struggling with a way to expand/duplicate data frame rows based on a condition. I also need to be able to expand rows in a variable way. I'll illustrate with this example.

I have this data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 10], [1,15], [2,10], [2, 15], [2, 20], [3, 10], [3, 15]], columns = ['id', 'var'])


df
Out[6]: 
   id  var
0   1   10
1   1   15
2   2   10
3   2   15
4   2   20
5   3   10
6   3   15
```

I would like to expand rows for both ID == 1 and ID  == 3. I would also like to expand each ID == 1 row by 1 duplicate each, and I would like to expand each ID == 3 row by 2 duplicates each. The result would look like this:

```
 df2
Out[8]: 
    id  var
0    1   10
1    1   10
2    1   15
3    1   15
4    2   10
5    2   15
6    2   20
7    3   10
8    3   10
9    3   10
10   3   15
11   3   15
12   3   15
13   3   15
```

I've been trying to use np.repeat, but I am failing to think of a way that I can use both ID condition and variable duplication numbers at the same time. Index ordering does not matter here, only that the rows are duplicated appropriately. I apologize in advance if this is an easy question. Thanks in advance for any help and feel free to ask clarifying questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
dup = {1: 1, 3:2} #what value and how much to add

res = df.copy()

for k, v in dup.items():
    for i in range(v):
        res = res.append(df.loc[df['id']==k], ignore_index=True)
res.sort_values(['id', 'var'], inplace=True)
res.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
res
#    id  var
#0    1   10
#1    1   10
#2    1   15
#3    1   15
#4    2   10
#5    2   15
#6    2   20
#7    3   10
#8    3   10
#9    3   10
#10   3   15
#11   3   15
#12   3   15
```

P.S. your desired solution had `7` values for `id 3` while your description implies `6` values.

Comment: Sorry about that! That was a typo on my part. Regardless, your solution worked perfectly for my larger data frame. Thank you for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I think below code gets your job done:

```
df_1=df.loc[df.id==1]
df_3=df.loc[df.id==3]
df1=df.append([df_1]*1,ignore_index=True)
df1.append([df_3]*2,ignore_index=True).sort_values(by='id')

    id  var
0   1   10
1   1   15
7   1   10
8   1   15
2   2   10
3   2   15
4   2   20
5   3   10
6   3   15
9   3   10
10  3   15
11  3   10
12  3   15
```

Comment: Have you tried this? You are just multiplying each element by 1 and 2 respectively. Test it and see.

Comment: I was able to use Zipa's code for my problem, but thank you for helping! This is an interesting way to tackle the problem as well.

Comment: @Zipa, yup i tested it and getting the desired output. But your code is efficient. Thanks!